# get selected option from document.getElementsByTagName("option")

Tags: javascript

I have html code this is a part of it :

```
<select id="year_marine_second_choose" style="display: none">
                    <option value="" style="display:none;"></option>
                    <option value="103">Lectures</option>
                    <option value="104">Courses</option>
                    <option value="105">Sheets</option>
                    <option value="106">Others</option>
                  </select>
                  <select id="year_marine_third_choose" style="display: none">
                    <option value="" style="display:none;"></option>
                    <option value="107">Lectures</option>
                    <option value="108">Courses</option>
                    <option value="109">Sheets</option>
                    <option value="110">Others</option>
                  </select>
                  <select id="year_marine_fourth_choose" style="display: none">
                    <option value="" style="display:none;"></option>
                    <option value="111">Lectures</option>
                    <option value="112">Courses</option>
                    <option value="113">Sheets</option>
                    <option value="114">Others</option>
                  </select>
```

this is the javascript code where the problem is :

```
var get_value = document.getElementsByTagName("option");
alert(get_value[5].value);
```

this code get the value of the 6th option .. any idea of how to get the value of the selected option by the user not the `[5]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript arrays start counting from `0`, so `[0]` is the first element. Which means you maybe need `alert(get_value[4].value);`

In case you need the selected option you can use:

```
var all_select = document.getElementsByTagName("select");
for (i = 0; i < all_select.length; i++) {
    all_select[i].onchange = function () {
        alert(this.value);
    }
}
```

**Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/VvBM9/)**

Comment: sorry bro but have to use getElementsByTagName coz i have like 400 option. I will try it on getElementsByTagName

Comment: @user2687618, sure. But you understand why `[5]` gave you the option 6?

Comment: @user2687618 , and btw, do you want to alert ooption value or the selected option only?

Comment: i was saying [5] only as example.. selected option only if u can help please

Comment: @user2687618, but why don't you use the `getElementById` to get the select? otherwise how do you know which `option` is selected? you do have `id`'s in each `select` so it looks like the best way to go

Comment: i will have to write a code with getElementById() repeated 100 times

Comment: @user2687618, ok. You could use `getElementsByTagName('select')` and a event listener to fire on change, would that work? then you need only 1 code

Comment: yea great you start to understand me . I search more about how to do it if you have an example of that will help a lot

Comment: @user2687618, check this: http://jsfiddle.net/VvBM9/ (I add that on my answer also)